# Who should our beta moderators be?

Tags: discussion, beta, moderators

The Workplace has reached public beta, and soon it will be time for us to get our first crop of moderators, as explained in the ["Moderator Pro Tempore" blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/):

> That’s why I am in the process of identifying and organizing a team of provisional Moderators from within each community (about three per site, starting  about seven days into the public Beta). This is a temporary, short-term appointment. Moderators Pro Tem focus and expedite [the essential needs of each new site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/). By the end of Beta, the community will be better suited to hold their own elections.
>
> Moderators in Stack Exchange have an interesting challenge. Beside the [normal activities of a Moderator](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), part of their function is to act as *liaison* — a role which links the Stack Exchange team with the individual communities.

Although during beta moderators will ultimately be selected by Stack Exchange, the purpose of this post is to seek out and propose candidates:

- Each nomination should be posted as an answer and it should include (at minimum) a link to the user's main and meta profile so we can check out their activity.
- Self nominations are encouraged, step up if you feel you can help.
- If you are nominated by someone else you should edit the answer and let us know if you accept or decline (explanation optional). If a nominee declines we will not delete the answer, as to not have someone else nominate them again.
- The nominations are not binding to Stack Exchange or the nominees.

Before nominating someone or accept / decline a nomination, you should read ["A Theory of Moderation"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) thoroughly to find out what's generally expected from moderators.

If you would like to learn more about the role, the [Water Cooler](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler), our main chat room, is full of moderators, feel free to ask us anything you'd like (hint: we are the ones with blue names). Furthermore [The Assembly](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly) was created specifically for users and moderators to discuss moderation activities, moderators from all over the network are there to answer your questions.

Comment: It's reasonable to be hesitant, but keep in mind that you'll never be alone, you'll be a part of a team that includes moderators from all over the network. First couple of days will be a bit awkward, but after you discover the delete button it gets a lot easier ;)

Comment: To whoever voted to delete this: Argh! The question may not be relevant anymore, but that doesn't mean it's not a piece of the site's history. There's no harm in keeping it around closed.

Answer (score 16):

I would like to nominate **NickC**

**Summary**: NickC has been providing good answers here, and has an impressive rep-per-post ratio over on Programmers.  His questions, answers and comments seem insightful and geared toward helping askers and answerers get the most out of this site.

---

### Workplace Profile

NickC has been active on The Workplace since the private beta. He is currently our top-ranked user by reputation, and has a respectable number of votes cast. His participation in meta posts has been lower than some other other candidates, but the quality of those posts has ranged from good to excellent (see also the network profile below).

[image]

---

### Network Profile

NickC's Stack Exchange network profile reflects substantial participation and contribution over on Programmers, with strong contributions on other sites as well, including [Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/143601/nickc), which I consider to be a major positive factor for any moderator candidate.

[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/48256.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/48256)

**Edited to accept nomination:** Thank you, I accept. I'd love to help this site and community get off the ground in any way I can.

Answer (score 9):

I would like to nominate **Rarity**

He's one of the highest rep users on the site, and is someone who works hard to make SE sites succeed (he's moderator of User Experience). I think he'd do a great job at helping this site succeed as well.

**Workplace/Network profile**

[image: profile for rarity at The Workplace, Q&A for members of the workforce navigating the professional setting]
 
[profile for rarity on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/465403.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/465403)

**Edited to accept the nomination**: I'd love to see this site succeed and as a current Moderator on another site I think I could help out the other pro temps

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to throw my hat in the ring. In addition to being part of the private beta, and being regularly active on the site ever since, I've written a fair amount on workplace issues outside of the site, and would love to continue to help the site grow its user base, while maintaining high quality.

In addition to this, I've gathered a number of "soft skills" while a member of the workforce that include conflict resolution, leadership skills, and writing skills; all of which will come in handy when stickier issues arise on the site that require mediation, conflict resolution, and a clear, written explanation of any actions I take.

Above all, I find The Workplace to be a great start to what I hope will grow to be a great site. I want to be a more active part of that, even if it is just in this temporary moderator role.

### Workplace profile

[image: profile for Normalocity at The Workplace, Q&A for members of the workforce navigating the professional setting]

### Network profile

[profile for Normalocity on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/90696.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/90696)

Comment: Finally someone nominated themselves! Kudos for stepping up, that's a valuable trait for a moderator.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to nominate **voretaq7**

voretaq7, I know you said in chat that you didn't think you could handle moderating another SE site, however I think you would do a great job as a moderator here and would like to ask you to reconsider.

I've appreciated the insight you've shown on meta, in chat, and with your answers.

**Workplace/Network profile**

[image: profile for voretaq7 at The Workplace, Q&A for members of the workforce navigating the professional setting]
 
[image: profile for voretaq7 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Answer (score 1):

I would like to nominate **Dipan Mehta**

He's a very active user, who I think will do a great job as a moderator for the site based on what I've seen from him in meta, on the main site, and in chat

**Workplace/Network profile**

[image: profile for dipan-mehta at The Workplace, Q&A for members of the workforce navigating the professional setting]
 
[profile for dipan-mehta on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/967533.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/967533)

**EDIT:**
*I am very grateful and honored to be listed here! Unfortunately, the kind of work cycles i have i fear that might become unavailable for random period. I truly appreciate it to be here, but it might hurt if i suddenly absent, hence i would request to decline this nomination. My sincere apology!*

Comment: @Dipan - it can be useful to have an "out of hours" moderator on a site, so don't let that stop you thinking about nominating yourself for moderator when the elections come round (which will be after the site graduates).